# Determinant of $A^T A$ where $A$ is a block lower triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a trick or simple way to compute $$\text{det}(A^T A)$$ where $A \in  \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $m \neq n$, is a block lower triangular matrix? An example of such a matrix would be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{B} & \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{D} & \mathbf{E} & \mathbf{F} \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where all bold face sub-matrices are, for example, $3 \times 2$.

I know that if $A$ is a square matrix with square blocks, it is just the product of the determinants of the blocks on the diagonal. However, I'm interested in the case when the blocks are non-square.

Note: If it helps, we may assume that the matrix $A$ has full column rank.

In addition to the determinant, is there a simple way to find the inverse, i.e., $(A^T A)^{-1}$?

Comment: There are the [Cauchy-Binet identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%E2%80%93Cauchy_identity#Generalization) connecting such determinants to scalar products of outer vector products. // An adapted and transposed variant of the QR algorithm should also give the result to all questions in a faster manner.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Doesn't the Cauchy-Binet formula require computing a sum over all subsets of size $m$ from the set of indices $\{1, \ldots, n\}$? In addition, this doesn't seem to take advantage of anything we might be able to garner from the fact that the matrix is block triangular.

Answer (score -1):

You are asking for the following determinant I think:

$$d = {\rm det}( \begin{bmatrix} 
A` A+B` B+D` D & B` C+D` E & D` F \\
C` B+E` D & C` C+E` E & E` F \\
F` D & F` E & F` F \end{bmatrix}) $$

where $A`$ is the transpose of $A$ for example.

Using [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) on the last row you get

$$ \begin{aligned} d & = {\rm det}( F` D) {\rm det}( \begin{bmatrix} B` C + E` D & D` F \\ C` C + E` E & E` F \end{bmatrix}) \\ & - {\rm det}(F` E){\rm det}( \begin{bmatrix}  A`A+B`B+D`D & D` F \\ C`B+E`D & E`F \end{bmatrix} ) \\ & + {\rm det}(F` F){\rm det} (\begin{bmatrix} A`A + B`B + D`D & B`C + D`E \\ C`B + E`D & C`C+E`E \end{bmatrix}) \end{aligned}$$

Comment: I was just giving an example in my post. The answer you gave doesn't seem to generalize to much larger examples.

Comment: Repeated application of Cramer's rule will do it..

Comment: Is this the most efficient/simple way to do this?

Comment: I don't know if it's the most efficient way. You are looking for a symbolic answer right?

Comment: Yes. I was wondering if there was a "nice" analytical solution.

Comment: $$\small d = A'•A•C'•C•F'•F+A'•A•E'•E•F'•F-A'•A•F'•E•E'•F+B'•B•C'•C•F'•F+B'•B•E'•E•F'•F-B'•B•F'•E•E'•F-C'•B•B'•C•F'•F-C'•B•D'•E•F'•F+C'•B•F'•E•D'•F+D'•D•C'•C•F'•F+D'•D•E'•E•F'•F-D'•D•F'•E•E'•F-E'•D•B'•C•F'•F-E'•D•D'•E•F'•F+E'•D•F'•E•D'•F+F'•D•B'•C•E'•F-F'•D•C'•C•D'•F+F'•D•D'•E•E'•F-F'•D•E'•E•D'•F$$ is the solution, it is just not very nice. Use Mathematica, Maple, MATLAB or any other symbolic math system to get to this. Here each matrix pair like $F'•D$ corresponds to the determinant ${\rm det}(F` D)$.